# Custom attribute text color

Tags: android, android-custom-view

Hello guys I'm new to all this. Sorry if I'm asking something simple. I want to change the text color of the custom attribute string.

attr.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="StoreCustomView">
        <attr name="strLimit" format="integer" />
        <attr name="strHeader" format="string" />
        <attr name="storeItemHeight" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="storeItemWidth" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="strLoader" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

fragment_home

```
                    <com.test.apps.myapp.customView.StoreCustomView
                        android:id="@+id/horizontalStoreList"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        custom:storeItemHeight="@dimen/v3_store_card_height"
                        custom:storeItemWidth="@dimen/v3_store_card_width"
                        custom:strHeader="@string/discover_stores_nearby"
                        custom:strLimit="6" />
```

so in this case i want to change strHeader text color

thank you in advance

i have tried android:textColor="" , android:color=""

Comment: We're going to need more information. What is `StoreCustomView`, exactly? The attributes you're setting on its tag will be applied only to the `StoreCustomView` itself, by default, so unless it's a subclass of a `View` that already knows about `android:textColor` or `andriod:color`, it's not going to do anything with those attributes on its own. Also, where and how is `strHeader` meant to be used? Are you handling it directly in `StoreCustomView`, or are you passing it to some inner, nested `View`? If the latter, you'll probably need to relay the color value to that nested `View`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.test.apps.myapp.customView.StoreCustomView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalStoreList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    custom:storeItemHeight="@dimen/v3_store_card_height"
    custom:storeItemWidth="@dimen/v3_store_card_width"
    custom:strHeader="@string/discover_stores_nearby"
    custom:strLimit="6"
    android:textColor="#FF0000" />
```